Problem customizing search_get_results() method in Django Admin page to get Custom Search
I have an app in Django and I would like to use this template:
{% load i18n static %}
{% if cl.search_fields %}

<div className="form-group">
  <div class="search-notes col-md-6 col-sm-12">Para busqueda de terminos exactos poner el texto entre comillas Ej  para editorial "VANGUARDIA PICTORICA" o en ISBN "978-959-7126-52-2"</div>
</div>

      <div class="for-group-container row"> 
       <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input type="text" name="no_reg" class="form-control" placeholder="Número de Registro" />
   <br>     
         <input type="text" name="inputTitulo" class="form-control" placeholder="Título" />
     <br>

          
     
    <br/>
     <input type="text" name="inputAutor" class="form-control" placeholder="Autor" />
    <br/>
    </div>      

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="inputEditorial" class="form-control" placeholder="Editorial" />
    <br/>

    <input type="text" name="inputDescriptor" class="form-control" placeholder="Descriptor" />
    <br/>

    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input type="text" name="inputResumen" class="form-control" placeholder="Resumen" />
    <br/>

<input type="submit" value="{% translate 'Search' %}">

  </div>

{% if show_result_count %}
    <span class="small quiet">{% blocktranslate count counter=cl.result_count %}{{ counter }} result{% plural %}{{ counter }} results{% endblocktranslate %} (<a href="?{% if cl.is_popup %}{{ is_popup_var }}=1{% endif %}">{% if cl.show_full_result_count %}{% blocktranslate with full_result_count=cl.full_result_count %}{{ full_result_count }} total{% endblocktranslate %}{% else %}{% translate "Show all" %}{% endif %}</a>)</span>
{% endif %}
{% for pair in cl.params.items %}
    {% if pair.0 != search_var %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ pair.0 }}" value="{{ pair.1 }}">{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% if cl.search_help_text %}
<br class="clear">
<div class="help" id="searchbar_helptext">{{ cl.search_help_text }}</div>
{% endif %}
</form></div>
{% endif %}

as to implement a custom search in the django admin page. My admin.py class whrere I would like to implement the custom search is as follows:
@admin.register(OpacLibro)
class LibroModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
#class LibroModelAdmin(DjangoQLSearchMixin,admin.ModelAdmin):

    form = LibroForm
    #search_form = LibroCustomSearchForm
    search_fields = ['no_reg','autor__nombre_autor','autor2__nombre_autor','editorial__nombre_editorial','colección__nombre_colección','localización','título']


    autocomplete_fields = ["autor", "editorial","descriptores"]

    
    #Codigo sugerido por AmazonQ
    def get_search_results(self, request, queryset, search_term):
        search_terms = search_term.split()
        q_objects = []
        print(request.GET)
        
        #Busqueda por Número de registro
        if 'no_reg' in request.GET and request.GET['no_reg']:
            no_reg = request.GET['no_reg']
            q_objects.append(Q(no_reg__icontains=no_reg))
        
        if 'inputTitulo' in request.GET and request.GET['inputTitulo']:
            título = request.GET['inputTitulo']
            q_objects.append(Q(título__icontains=titulo))
            print(q_objects)

        # Search in the author fields
        if 'inputAutor' in request.GET and request.GET['inputAutor']:
            autor = request.GET['inputAutor']
            q_objects.append(Q(autor__nombre_autor__icontains=autor))
            print(q_objects)

        if 'inputDescriptor' in request.GET and request.GET['inputDescriptor']:
            descriptores = request.GET['inputDescriptor']
            q_objects.append(Q(descriptores__nombre_descriptor__icontains=descritpores))
            print(q_objects)

        if 'inputResumen' in request.GET and request.GET['inputResumen']:
            resumen = request.GET['inputResumen']
            q_objects.append(Q(resumen__icontains=resumen))
            print(q_objects)

        # Search in the editorial (publisher) field
        if 'inputEditorial' in request.GET and request.GET['inputEditorial']:
            editorial = request.GET['inputEditorial']
            q_objects.append(Q(editorial__nombre_editorial__icontains=editorial))
            
        print(request.GET)

        
        
        if q_objects:
            qs = queryset.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, q_objects))
            print(q_objects)
        else:
            qs = queryset

        return qs, True

    list_display = ('no_reg','título','get_descriptores','get_autor','get_autor2','get_autor3','get_editorial','get_coleccion','fecha_registro','get_lugar_de_impresion','localización')

    # list_filter = [AutorFilter,EditorialFilter]
    list_per_page = 10


    


    def get_last_book_register(self):
        return OpacLibro.objects.all().aggregate(Max('no_reg'))['no_reg__max'] + 1

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(LibroModelAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['no_reg'].initial = self.get_last_book_register()
        form.base_fields['signatura'].initial = str(self.get_last_book_register()) + "-"
        #form.base_fields['isbn'].initial = {'text-transform': 'uppercase'}
        return form

My problem is that when I enter a search term in no_reg as example, I do not see any results in the changelist, and when i place debug prints in the code, it says the request search terms are empty, and I see in the runserver logs that is not like that ie:
[17/Jul/2024 15:07:28] "GET /adminopac/opaclibro/?no_reg=1900&inputTitulo=&inputAutor=&inputEditorial=&inputDescriptor=&inputResumen= HTTP/1.1" 302 0

The other issue is that I see a redirection http status code 302, and when I fall back to the classic search of django it throws a 200 http status code, I previously tryied to use django-admin-search package but is asking for a mantainer, and only one input field worked.thanks in advance.
